# What do you call a speculative law?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, vocabulary

The Moore's law is an empirical law based on empirical observations. What do you call a law that's purely speculative? Is there such a thing? What kind of terms would scientists use to refer to such a thing?

Comment: Do you mean a *conjecture*? A proposed law for which there is not yet sufficient proof?